# Check if input field has focus and pass input variable to function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field which will be updated every x seconds:

```
<input type="number" name="METER" id="METER.NUM" min="0" max="500" step="0.10" oninput="setMeter(currentValue);" >
```

Now, I want to check if the input field has focus (user clicked into the field).

If the field has focus:

- I will stop updating the field and the user can put some value into the field
- Then the value should be passed to a function

---

This is the javascript code:

```
if (document.getElementById(array[0]).name == "METER") {
    // check if the input field has focus
    // stop updating
}
```

What's wrong with my approch/code? I think one problem is, that the function call by oninput doesn't work. But it works by onClick.

Comment: have you tried using the 'onChange' event. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Comment: @Onilol I've seen that question but I don't know how to use $("..").is(":focus")

Comment: I've tried this:                         if(document.getElementById(array[0]).is(":focus"))

Comment: @Philies that checks if an element has the pseudo-class focus . Try something like this : `$(my_element_id_here).is(":focus")`

Comment: @Onilol: OP does not use jQuery, but pure Javascript ;)

Comment: @Onilol Sorry, did not see that. I proposed a fix for the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onfocus = myFunction()`

```js
function setMeter() {
    console.log('hey, im focused');
    // do stuff here
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="METER" id="METER.NUM" min="0" max="500" step="0.10" onfocus="setMeter();" >
```

Comment: Idea: use `onfocus="setMeter(this);"` and `function setMeter(el)` to access properties of clicked element as well